# Character Vector of loaded packages

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I am currently trying to translate my loaded packages into a character vector to use in the pkgDep function. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this? Currently my results are formatted as a list, and using the unlist()function has not worked for me. I think rapply would do the trick, but I am running into issues on how to set up the function. I have pasted my code below. Thanks!

```
x <- loaded_packages()
typeof(x)
#need a character vector with package names to pass into function
pkgList <- pkgDep(x, availPkgs = pkgdata, suggests=TRUE)`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `search()` function to see the packages currently loaded.

```
 x <- search()
 x
 #  [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:dplyr"     "package:stats"    
 #  [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
 #  [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
 # [10] "package:base"   

 pkgList <- pkgDep(x, availPkgs = pkgdata, suggests=TRUE)`
```

If you can tell us what `pkgDep()` function does, we can get the loaded packages list in specific format.

Comment: This is what pkgDep does, but I think I need to define a function that will process my x into a list. It would have to take each element in the list and insert it into an vector. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/vignettes/miniCRAN-dependency-graph.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
x <- search()
```

As per [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-April/032705.html) link.